# How to create a counter for each new instance of string in python?

Tags: python, count

I was wondering how I can create a counter for a new instance of a specific string (#####) in a list. I then want to append this counter to the string:

```
##### 
pears 
oranges 
##### 
apples 
grapes 
##### 
grapes 
oranges 
#####
apples 
pears
oranges
grapes
```

The output will look something like this:

```
#####_1 
pears 
oranges 
#####_2    
apples 
grapes 
#####_3  
grapes 
oranges 
#####_4 
apples 
pears
oranges
grapes
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking, what you're trying to do, or why you're trying to do it. Perhaps adding some sample code or pseudo-code will help clarify your problem.

Comment: @DavidZemens Why is it not clear? Are there specific examples you can give?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId it's not clear whether OP wants to count instances of strings or to dynamically create variables/refrences/names -- two very different problems. Looks like someone has revised the OP for terminology, though, as well as output expectations. Seems a bit more clear now.

Comment: @DavidZemens Yes you have a good point, the initial wording was unclear in this regard.

Comment: Did you _completely change your expected output_? You used to have, e.g., `#####` and `pears_1` but now you have `#####_1` and `pears`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

File input.txt

```
##### 
pears 
oranges 
##### 
apples 
grapes 
##### 
grapes 
oranges 
#####
apples 
pears
oranges
grapes
```

File run.py

```
lines = [l.strip() for l in open('input.txt', 'r').readlines()]
hash_count = 0

for line in lines:
    if line == '#####':
        hash_count += 1
        print(line)
    else:
        print(line + '_' + str(hash_count))
```

Run it:

```
$ python run.py
```

Output:

```
#####
pears_1
oranges_1
#####
apples_2
grapes_2
#####
grapes_3
oranges_3
#####
apples_4
pears_4
oranges_4
grapes_4
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Please explain your solution so the OP (and other users) can learn how it works.

Comment: I agree with your comment. But I think the code above under run.py is easy to understand if you have gone through the first Python tutorials. Writing explanations is not something I am good at right now, but I will surely try to work on it. Thanks.

Comment: Your output is different from what the OP says they want - adding indexes to the non-hash lines isn't what is shown as expected output.

Comment: @barny The OP changed expected output! xD

Comment: Sorry - edit your answer some minor way and I will remove downvote. Nice work (not!), ananth.

Comment: Im really sorry about this, I did try and be more explicit in my question, and I also changed the desired output. I feel a bit silly at this point